# No property lastname found for type User (JPA)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

User.java:

```
package com.hodor.booking.jpa.domain;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
public class User extends AbstractPersistable {

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String email;

    private Date birthday;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public Date getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setBirthday(Date birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }
}
```

UserRepository.java:

```
package com.hodor.booking.jpa.repository;

import com.hodor.booking.jpa.domain.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

/**
 * For Spring Data JPA query methods see:
 * http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods
 */
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    public User findByEmail(String email);
    public User findByLastname(String lastName);
}
```

UserService.java:

```
package com.hodor.booking.service;

import com.hodor.booking.jpa.domain.User;
import com.hodor.booking.jpa.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public User saveUser(User user) {
        Assert.notNull(user);
        return userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
    }

    public List<User> findAll() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    public User findOne(Long id) {
        Assert.notNull(id);
        return userRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    public User findByEmail(String email) {
        Assert.hasLength(email);
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }

    public User findByLastname(String lastName) {
        Assert.hasLength(lastName);
        return userRepository.findByLastname(lastName);
    }
}
```

UserController:

```
package com.hodor.booking.controller;

import com.hodor.booking.jpa.domain.User;
import com.hodor.booking.service.UserService;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.Api;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/users")
@Api(value = "users", description = "User resource endpoint")
public class UserController {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<User> index() {
        log.debug("Getting all users");
        return userService.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public User get(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        return userService.findOne(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{lastName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public User get(@PathVariable("lastName") String lastName) {
        return userService.findByLastname(lastName);
    }
}
```

StackTrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.hodor.booking.jpa.repository.UserRepository com.hodor.booking.service.UserService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property lastname found for type User!
```

**Problem:**

I added the findByLastname Method and I can't find the problem (I am new to this).

Comment: Have you try to annotated your User Instance Fields with the `@Column` JPA annotation??

Comment: Thanks.. where in the code would I do that?

Comment: In the User class... annotate the instance attributes... Example: `@Column private String firstName;`

Comment: Your property is `lastName`, but the error is about `lastname`. Check the getters/setters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had never used Spring... but reading the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html) about `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository`, I suggest to rename your method: `findByLastname` as `findByLastName` in the `UserRepository` interface...

It seems this functionalty generates JPA queries by reading and parsing the defined methods at a given interface that extends from `JpaRepository` ... and by saying "findByLastname", Spring expects to find a property at User Entity as: `lastname` and not `lastName`

Comment: Typo as usual. Thanks mate.